# What is wrong with my Angular ng-foreach binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following validation summary:

```
<div ng-if="client.showValidations" class="validation-summary-errors text-danger">
    <span>There be errors!</span>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in client.validationErrors">{{value}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Where `validationErrors` is a collection of object with `key` and `value` properties. When I have validation errors, the summary displays them as follows:

> {"key":"FullName","value":"The FullName field is required."}

While I am trying to only display `value`, I am seeing the whole object being output as a literal. Where have I gone astray and how?

Comment: Try {{client.validationErrors.value}}. Just a wild guess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a collection of objects, so I assume it looks like:

```
[ {key: "1", value: "value1"}, {key: "2", value: "value2"}, ... ]
```

What you are doing, is iteration over array and you receive elements:

```
{key: "1", value: "value1"}
```

You can try following way:

```
<div ng-if="client.showValidations" class="validation-summary-errors text-danger">
<span>There be errors!</span>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="error in client.validationErrors">{{error.value}}</li>
</ul>
```